# export data from elasticsearch to neo4j

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, export

I'm looking for the best method to export data from elasticsearch.
is there something better than running a query with from/size, until all the data exported?

specifically, i want to copy parts of it to Neo4j, if there is any plugin for that..

Comment: have u found out any solution? Need help..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any kind of the plugin, which can do what you want.

But you can write one. I recommend you to use [Jest](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest), because default ElasticSearch Java client using different Lucene version than Neo4j and those versions are incompatible.

Second option is export data from ElasticSearch to CSV and then use [Load CSV](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-load-csv.html) in Neo4j. This approach is good enough if import data is one time operation.